# Click Flash banner > watch movie > redirect to page automatically without clicking again – using clickTAG in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, redirect, clicktag

**Flow of banner: Some animation > stop(); > BTN > click > gotoAndPlay next frame > run movie > last frame = redirect to URL**

To minimize the clicks in a flashbanner I need to have one button with a clickTAG assigned. After clicking this button the banner will run a short animation afterwards and then redirect without anymore clicking. How is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a frame script in the last frame, so, you call a function to stop the animation and open the new URL (redirect)

```
 // mc.totalFrames-1 = last frame
 mc.addFrameScript(mc.totalFrames-1, lastFrameReached);

 function lastFrameReached():void 
 {
     trace("stopping the animation");
     mc.stop();
     navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683670/click-flash-banner-watch-movie-redirect-to-page-automatically-without-clicki"));
 }
```